# ADODB.RecordSet doesn't delimit CSV columns

Tags: .net, csv, vbscript, iis-7.5, adodb

I have a VBScript which uses `ADODB.RecordSet` to get all items of a delimited CSV file. Here a piece of the script:

```
Set rsSource = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set cnxExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnxExcel.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
cnxExcel.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & CheminSource & ";Extended Properties='Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
cnxExcel.Open
rsSource.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & Fichier & "]", cnxExcel, 3
If rsSource.EOF AND rsSource.BOF Then
  RecordSetVide = true
Else
  rsSource.MoveFirst
  NbColonne = 1         
  For Each adoFld in rsSource.Fields
    ReDim Preserve TabColonne(NbColonne)
    TabColonne(NbColonne) = adoFld.Name         
  Next
End If
```

The problem is that I get one output non delimited and the semicolons visible:

```
item1;item2;item3...
```

instead of:

```
item1
item2
item3
...
```

This code used to run well on II6 (W2K) but when moving to IIS7.5 (W2008R2), it seems that it doesn't take into consideration the delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/):

> ## Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0
>
> ### Delimited columns
>
> ```
> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;
> Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";
> ```
>
> The delimiter can be specified in the registry at the following location:
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text`
>   `"Format" = "TabDelimited"`
>   or
>   `"Format" = "Delimited(;)"`
>
> [How to Use JET in 64 bit environments](http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments)

Comment: thanks ! This solved my problem but the key wasn't in the path you specified but : HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text

Comment: Then you have a 64-bit system. Added the link covering JET in 64-bit environments to the quote.